# Dynamically set header value for SFTP connector in Mulesoft

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, mule-connector

How to set header value either true or false dynamically.  I need to set value using variable either true or false but it is not setting.  Can anyone help on this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These are not really SFTP headers but [DataWeave CSV format properties](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-formats#reader_writer_properties). You can not set them dynamically in the UI. You can use the method described in the [documentation to set dynamic format properties](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-cookbook-writer-prop-mule). For that you will probably need to do it in a transform component after the SFTP read operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `choice` router and provide a `sftp:read` event processor in each route with a different value of this property.